# how to get the count and name of each element

Tags: mysql

Here I have a situation where I'm not `certain` about the `field elements`.

suppose I have this `dynamic fields`

**table:mytable**

```
+my_column_name+

 |"colleges"|
 |"schools" |
 |"global"  |
 |"temple"  |
    .
    .
    .

 |"business"|
```

I'm trying to get all the `fields` as well as `count`.

```
SELECT count()

   FROM mytable

   WHERE my_column_name =
```

Please help me to dynamically get all fields, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What do you mean "Dynamic Fields"? That sounds very scary.

Comment: these `fields`  `"colleges"
 "schools" 
 "global"  
 "temple"  ` are `dynamic` i do not know them

Comment: that means i cannot use comparision like this `my_column_name ="college"`  ...... and so on.

Comment: Yes. I see. It's not the columns that are dynamic, but rather the data in them. You just want a count of records for each distinct value in `+my_Column_name+`. If so @Bill's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't fields, they are just data values. As far as understand your question, this should be solved with a simple group-by query:

```
SELECT my_column_name as `what_you_call_field`, COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY my_column_name;
```

If you mean something different, please edit your question above and post an example of what you want a hypothetical query result to look like.